# Count palindromes of type XYYX

Tags: string, algorithm, optimization

The following is an interview question. I didn't make it through as a better and efficient answer was expected, which I didn't have.

---

Given a string S we need to find the number of palindromes of pattern XYYX where X and Y are any character from the same String S.

Note: We cannot change the order of characters in string S. Value of X and Y can be same also, but their position needs to be different in String S.

Also, two strings are different if their indexes in string S are different for any character in final string

Example: Say string is S=abbaab, then answer is 4.

The four such palindromes are :

```
abba [Indexes : 1,2,3,4] 
abba [Indexes : 1,2,3,5] 
baab [Indexes : 3,4,5,6]
baab [Indexes : 2,4,5,6]
```

So how to count number of such palindromes. Length of string can go up to 1000000. So what can be best way to do it?

Comment: *Given a string S we need* - What is with the "we" bit?

Comment: We means: "Those who gave him his homework" ;)

Comment: I gave up on homework 20 years ago. Why should I start again?

Comment: @BitTickler Its not homework:(

Comment: @EdHeal One reason could be that the crossword puzzles in your fav paper are getting boring ;)

Comment: @EdHeal Its not homework guys :/

Comment: @EdHeal I am new to stackoverflow. Also, I got a solution, but it wont suffice with strings of large length :(

Comment: So the company that you work for like palindromes?

Comment: @EdHeal It was an interview question . I didn't make it through as a better and efficient answer was expected , which I didnt had.

Comment: @HackAround Try to think of a finite state machine which terminates once a palindrome is found. Input events to the state machine is the next character from S. If the character does not yield a transition to the FSM's next state, it is not a palindrome and you can drop this possibility. Else keep it until it fails or ends. Now you only need a rule when to "spawn" a new instance of your FSM and how you keep your active FSM instances while you progress over your input S.

Comment: @BitTickler Ohk. Can you please elaborate a bit. Thanks.

Comment: The first answer given also looks good.

Comment: @BitTickler No its not. It is considering all indexes as consecutive. But in example also, they are not

Comment: Your second given example results makes me think you are looking for something like  ``XYYX*``.

Comment: @BitTickler And how to get that for such a long string input ?

Comment: This is a question from a live contest (as of the time of OP's post): https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/world-codesprint-5/challenges/short-palindrome . Shame on you OP.

Answer (score 0):

As found in the discussion section of the question, the goal is not to find "real" palindromes but something like "XYYX*" where each of the "X*" matched is counted.

This implies that you need to maintain some search state while iterating over the input `S`, as on each position of `S`, multiple palindromes might be possible.

Now consider the (worst case?) input of "abbaaaa...." (starts with "abba" and ends with `(1000000 - 4)` 'a'-characters. How many state instances would we have to maintain in this case? The answer depends a bit on how the state-machine (the state maintained) is defined.

The state machine mentioned is a detector of the matches. Let's see some code (F# chosen):

```
type PState =
  | X of char
  | Y0 of char * char
  | Y1 of char * char
  | X1 of char * char
  | XN of char * char
  | End

let tryProgress c = function
    | X(x) -> Some(Y0(x,c))
    | Y0(x,y) -> if c = y then Some(Y1(x,y)) else None
    | Y1(x,y) -> if c = x then Some(X1(x,y)) else None
    | X1(x,y) -> if c = x then Some(XN(x,y)) else Some (End)
    | XN(x,y) -> if c = x then Some(XN(x,y)) else Some (End)
    | End -> failwith "This instance is done and should have been dismissed."

let count (s : string) =
    s.ToCharArray()
    |> Array.fold (fun (states,counter) c ->
            let counter1 = ref 0
            (X(c)) :: (states 
            |> List.map (fun fsm ->
                    let res = tryProgress c fsm
                    // printfn "%A -> %c -> %A" fsm c res
                    match res with
                    | None -> None
                    | Some(X1(x,y)) ->
                        counter1 := !counter1 + 1
                        Some(X1(x,y))
                    | Some(XN(x,y)) -> 
                        counter1 := !counter1 + 1
                        Some(XN(x,y))
                    | Some(End) -> 
                        counter1 := !counter1 + 1
                        None
                    | Some(fsm1) -> Some(fsm1)
                )
            |> List.filter (fun mfsm -> match mfsm with | Some(fsm) -> true | None -> false)
            |> List.map (fun mfsm -> Option.get mfsm))
            , (!counter1 + counter)
        ) ([],0)
    |> snd

let s = "abbaab"
count s

(*
    Yields: 
    val it : int = 4
    as hoped for.
*)
```

Type `PState` is a discriminated union which describes the individual states of the state machine along with the data required for the respective states.

The `tryProgress` function takes an instance of the fsm and the next input character from S and returns a `Pstate option` result. If the character does not result in a new possible state, this function returns `None` else it returns `Some <resulting state>`.

Last not least, the `count` function iterates over the characters in the input string (could as well read an input file char-wise...) and applies the `tryProgress` function to each active state machine. As well it decides, which instances to "forget" and which to maintain and it decides when to increase the counter of found pseudo-palindromes.

Coming back to our allegedly worst case input scenario, the number of FSM instances kept would increase with the number of characters as also the case X = Y does not help reduce the number of states to be preserved. Most of those instances would be in state `XN('a','a')` until the sequence ends.

As such, I am tempted to classify the problem as an ill-posed one.
(`"aaaaaaa" -> [0,1,2,3;0,1,2,4;0,1,2,5;0,1,2,6; 1,2,3,4; 1,2,3,5; 1,2,3,6; ...]`).

**UPDATE**

As another language was requested for the code sample, here the ever popular C++ version:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>

enum class PStateName
{
    X,Y0,Y1,X1,XN,END,FAIL
};

struct PState 
{
    PStateName state;
    char x;
    char y;

    PState(PStateName s, char x0, char y0 = '\0')
    : state(s)
    , x(x0)
    , y(y0)
    {

    }

    static PState MakeX(char x0)
    {
        return PState(PStateName::X, x0);
    }
    static PState To_Y0(const PState &pre, char y0)
    {
        return PState(PStateName::Y0,pre.x, y0);
    }
    static PState To_Y1(const PState&pre)
    {
        return PState(PStateName::Y1,pre.x,pre.y);
    }
    static PState To_X1(const PState&pre)
    {
        return PState(PStateName::X1,pre.x,pre.y);
    }
    static PState To_XN(const PState&pre)
    {
        return PState(PStateName::XN,pre.x,pre.y);
    }
    static PState To_End(const PState&pre)
    {
        return PState(PStateName::END,pre.x,pre.y);
    }
    static PState To_Fail(const PState&pre)
    {
        return PState(PStateName::FAIL,pre.x,pre.y);
    }
};

PState Progress(const PState& current, char c)
{
    switch(current.state)
    {
        case PStateName::X:
            return PState::To_Y0(current,c);
            break;
        case PStateName::Y0:
            if(c == current.y)
                return PState::To_Y1(current);
            else
                return PState::To_Fail(current);
            break;
        case PStateName::Y1:
            if(c == current.x)
                return PState::To_X1(current);
            else
                return PState::To_Fail(current);
            break;
        case PStateName::X1:
            if(c == current.x)
                return PState::To_XN(current);
            else
                return PState::To_End(current);
            break;
        case PStateName::XN:
            if(c == current.x)
                return PState::To_XN(current);
            else
                return PState::To_End(current);
            break;
        case PStateName::END:
            throw std::exception(/*"Instances in state End should have been dismissed and never show here."*/);
            break;
        case PStateName::FAIL:
            throw std::exception(/*"Instances in state FAIL should have been dismissed and never show here."*/);
            break;
        default:
            throw std::exception(/*"Fix me! Unknown state in a switch statement!"*/);
            break;
    }
}

typedef std::list<PState> StateList;

StateList nextChar( const StateList& actives, char c, size_t &counter )
{
    StateList result;
    for(auto fsm : actives)
    {
        PState fsm1 = Progress(fsm,c);
        switch(fsm1.state)
        {
            case PStateName::FAIL: // Do nothing - weed out and do not count it.
                break;
            case PStateName::X1:
                counter++;
                result.push_back(fsm1);
                break;
            case PStateName::XN:
                counter++;
                result.push_back(fsm1);
                break;
            case PStateName::END:
                counter++;
                break;
            default:
                result.push_back(fsm1);
                break;            
        }
    }

    result.push_back(PState::MakeX(c));
    return result;
}

size_t countString( const std::string& s)
{
    size_t counter = 0;
    StateList current;
    for(auto c : s)
    {
        current = nextChar(current,c,counter);
    }
    return counter;
}

size_t countFile( const std::string& filePath)
{
    size_t counter = 0;
    StateList current;
    // TODO: read file char by char and feed it to nextChar as shown in the countString() function.
    return counter;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    std::string s("abbaab");
    std::cout <<"\"" <<  s << "\": " << countString(s) << std::endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @BitTracker Can the code be in C++/Java . Am not able to even try my test case to understand the code :(

Comment: @HackAround And what if your next job interview confronts you with a functional programmer? :)  One of those who insists that functional programs are easier to read?! :) Lets see if someone else writes the answer in one of your desired languages - if not, I will add in a few days.

Comment: If input is "aaaaaab" then output am getting is 9 in this code. But in actual it should be 15

Comment: @HackAround Then you are not looking for the pattern I coded the state machine for. It should be easy for you to tell, how the state machine should look like for what you want. It does not seem to be "XYYXX*" obviously. I deduced that pattern from your list of found matches in your question.

Comment: @HackAround You should be able to give the "regular expression" for what you are looking for. From the text description alone, I cannot conclusively decide the pattern you are looking for. The state machine approach actually does exactly that. It implements the DFA of a regular expression.